# Didn't Configure "binddn" and "bindpw" in "/etc/nslcd.conf" but nslcd able to connect to Openldap server and authenticate users

Tags: openldap

How does openldap allowed nslcd to access DB without authentication?

**Server Side Configuration**

Started slapd service and modified olcSuffix, olcRootDN, olcRootPW, olcAccess as shown below

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=sam,dc=com

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=samio,dc=sam,dc=com

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}v3AAHxk25g32BxWSUTyWUQltdFqZPbbJ

dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read by dn.base="cn=samio,dc=sam,dc=com" read by * none
```

Then added nss.ldif inetorgperson.ldif cosine.ldif as shown below.

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif 
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/nss.ldif 
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif
```

Now Added some users as shown below.

```
ldapadd -x -w samio -D cn=samio,dc=sam,dc=com -f users.ldif
```

**users.ldif**

```
dn: dc=sam,dc=com
dc: sam
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain

dn: cn=samio,dc=sam,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: samio
description: LDAP Manager

dn: ou=People,dc=sam,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People

dn: ou=Group,dc=sam,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Group



dn: uid=pinehead,ou=People,dc=sam,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: pinehead
uid: pinehead
uidNumber: 9999
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/pinehead
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: pinehead [Lead Penguin (at) Linux Academy]
userPassword: pinehead
shadowLastChange: 17058
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7

dn: uid=tcox,ou=People,dc=sam,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: tcox
uid: tcox
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/tcox
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: Terry Cox [Super Dude (at) Linux Academy]
userPassword: tcox
shadowLastChange: 17058
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
```

**Client Side configuration**

Now on the client machine, Installed all the required packages and ran the following

```
authconfig --update --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=172.31.7.3 --ldapbasedn=dc=sam,dc=com --enablemkhomedir
```

I could able to successfully login now.

```
[root@25811cb8b71c ~]# ssh tcox@localhost
Password: 
[tcox@25811cb8b71c ~]$ pwd
/home/tcox
[tcox@25811cb8b71c ~]$
```

Im surprised that how does the Openldap server allowed the nslcd client to access db without authenticating? Help me know what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1):

This means your server allows for anonymous bind, which you can disable :

Create an ldif file, say `authbind.ldif` and add the following :

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDisallows
olcDisallows: bind_anon
-

dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc
```

Then run :

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f authbind.ldif
```

---

The above works in OpenLDAP Online Configuration (OLC) mode.

For those using the old static configuration, just add the following to `slapd.conf` and restart your server :

```
disallow bind_anon
require authc
```